# How to create a Table in Oracle which has a variable of type number?

Tags: oracle

Suppose I want to store the social security numbers with a prefix letter 'S' (eg. S123456789) or a driving license number D (eg. D12345).

Is there any function or method to prefix it? Or patters? 
I just need a hint.

Comment: Social security numbers and driving licence numbers are called "numbers" but they are actually strings of (of usually only numeric digits but sometimes more) characters. In any case, they are not really numbers. You don't add, multiply or divide two social security numbers. So, there is no need to store them as numbers. Use `VARCHAR` instead and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a "code", whereby the first two digits represent your letter 'D' = X or 'S' = Y (X and Y are integers) and the rest of your number could be your numerical part - that would mean a lot of parsing though and my scheme won't work for more than 1 letter (without complex coding).

Why not put the letter in a separate column? What is your actual business requirement? 0-padding is out because 0-padded numbers appear to have to be VARCHARs - which is not what you want as I understand it.

In fact, you'll have to start with 'K' = 10 (then 'Z' = 36, A = 37) &c., because if you start with 'A' = 10, then what's 'K' going to be? Again, why do you want to do this? You could also have 'A' = 10, 'B' = 11... 'Z' = 36. If you only have a couple of letters in your system, I would use a small lookup table for the code and have a pure number in a INTEGER column.

What's wrong with parsing VARCHARs? You'll be parsing your numbers anyway. Personally,  I'd go with a lookup table and separate field **or** a VARCHAR. But, I may have given you a couple of ideas? P.s. welcome to the forum!